# How to find the mid-point of a n-dimensional cone?

Tags: geometry

An n-cone is a geometric figure consist of a base of (n-1) dimensional equilateral simplex plus one vertical vertex such that the height is $h$. The side-length of the base is $2l$.

Mid-point is the point whose distance away from each vertex is the same.

A 1-cone is a segment of height $h$. The mid-point is at $h/2$ away from the vertex.

A 2-cone is a isosceles triangle with height $h$. The mid-point is at $h/2+l^2/2h$ away from the vertex.

A 3-cone is a tetrahedron with a equilateral triangle as the base.

I am having difficulty finding a general formula for the position of mid point of n-cone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance from the midpoint of the $(n-1)$-simplex to a vertex of this simplex is $c:=\sqrt{2}l\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}$. Let $d$ be the distance from the vertical vertex to the midpoint of the $n$-cone. Then by Pythagoras' theorem it holds $d^2 = (h-d)^2+c^2 = d^2 -2hd +h^2 +c^2$ and thus $2hd = h^2 + 2\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)l^2$. Finally, $$d = \frac{h}{2}+\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{l^2}{h}.$$